# Unable to create datasource from mysql in pentaho

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, pentaho

[image]I am using pentaho 8.1 and connecting to mysql on localhost. databse connection is created. it is throwing error at data source creation when choose database(tables)(refer to attached image)

Kindly help!

Comment: You didn't post the image.

Comment: Please post the image, or ***preferably*** the error log. In the meanwhile check if the `lib` directory, which is sitting next to your spoon.bat/spoon.sh contains the jdbc driver, which should be named `mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` up to the version number.

Comment: it is already there -mysql-connector-java-8.0.13 in lib of data integration.This image is about Penaho BA(business Analysis) and this jar file is also exist in lib of tomcat.

Comment: It might not work with latest jar .. try with 5.1.46 .. it will work ..